# How to define separate username/password for rsync source and destination?

Tags: rsync, rhel

I'm trying to setup an rsync command from a VM to a QNAP but I need to define the username/password for each (they are different values) in one rsync line. I would like to use a password file (utilizing --password-file=rsync_pass) if possible so the passwords are not in plain text in the command line.

Comment: More info and clarification needed. Are you talking about a situation where both the source and destination are remote? How are you connecting to them (over ssh, over the rsync protocol, something else)? If ssh, can you use private key authentication?

Comment: Apologies, sir. In this case, it is going to be over rsync protocol, and the rsync cron job is on a RHEL7 VM. The source is and iSCSI path on a host that the RHEL7 VM has access to, and the destination is a NAS that has rsync enabled and an rsync username/password setup. My initial rsync line was going to the the following, before I took into account that I needed the username and password for source AND destination: rsync $args –password-file=rsync_pass root@vm2::/ISCSI_PATH 192.168.169.15/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/CoreQnap1_REP